# How to maintain map dimensions consistent across multiple figures in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am creating several different maps of the conterminous United States using ggplot 2. the back ground is the "states" map from the "maps" library. each figure I need to create has different facetting (e.g. 1 column of 3 maps, 2 columns of 3 maps each, 1 single map), all showing the entire outline of the conterminous U.S. I need to maintain the dimensions so that when I save the maps to pngs and put them in a report, the United states is not stretched in any way when compared to one another. is there a simple way to maintain this consistency?

Comment: Are you using `coord_map` or `coord_quickmap`?

Comment: neither, I'm using lat/lon data and not projecting it.

Comment: Both of those are intended to preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: great, will try them. do you want to to write this as an answer?